# A point is a saddle point when $D<0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Show that if $x'=(x,y) \ \  $ is a critical point of a $\mathcal{C}^3$ function $f$ such that: $$D=f_{xx}(x')f_{yy}(x')-(f_{xy}(x'))^2<0$$

Then there are points $x$ and $z$ near $x'$ such that $f(x)>f(x') \ \ $ and $\ \ f(z)<f(x')$

I know that since
$$
D=\left|\,\begin{matrix}
f_{xx}(x') & f_{xy}(x') \\
f_{xy}(x') & f_{yy}(x')
\end{matrix}\right|<0,
$$ 
there is a saddle point at that location, but I'm not sure how I could show that in a more formal proof or more formal explanation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given condition says that the matrix
$$
H(x')=\left(\begin{matrix} f_{xx}(x')& f_{xy}(x')\\
f_{xy}(x')& f_{yy}(x')
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
has a negative determinant and hence real eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\mu$, with
$$
\lambda<0<\mu.
$$

Let $\xi$, $\eta$ corresponding eigenvectors and define the functions
$$g(t)=f(x'+t\xi),\quad 
h(t)=f(x'+t\eta).$$
Then
$$
g'(0)=\xi\cdot\big(f_x(x'),f_y(x')\big)=0, \quad
h'(0)=\eta\cdot\big(f_x(x'),f_y(x')\big)=0,
$$
but
$$
g''(0)=\xi^tH(x')\xi=\lambda \|\xi\|^2<0,
$$
while
$$
h''(0)=\eta^tH(x')\eta=\mu \|\eta\|^2>0.
$$
This means that $t=0$ is a strict local maximum for $g$ and a strict local minimum for $h$. Hence, for some $t$ sufficiently small
$$
f(x'+t\xi)=h(t)<f(x')<g(t)=f(x'+t\eta).
$$

Comment: To the OP: Since $H$ is symmetric, $\xi$ and $\eta$ are orthogonal in the $xy$-plane. You can imagine the surface $z=f(x,y)$ at the critical point as having two "ribs" that cross orthogonally. The rib parallel to $\xi$ is locally similar to a downward opening parabola, and the rib parallel to $\eta$ is locally similar to an upward opening parabola. This is what conjures the image of a saddle.

Comment: This is very good way of explaining it.

Comment: @alex.jordan that's an excellent way of explaining it, I knew it was a saddle but now I could think of a saddle point, thank you and thank you to the person who answered it

Comment: Hi, sorry for reviving this old post, but I have a question, how did you calculate the first and second derivatives of$\ g$ and$\ h$? I know it's a dumb question, but I just don't get it, thanks.